# Deleting items from an array and collapsing it after

Tags: arrays, perl

Using Perl, I have an array of IP addresses that I'm storing in an array. There are many operations done on the elements in the array and one of them is to delete an IP address. I know I can use the `delete` function, but that leaves an empty spot in the array. Is there a function/way to delete an item from the array and collapse/shift the elements so there are no empty spots.

For example, say there are 10 elements in the array. We delete the 3rd element. Then there are only 9 elements and the 4th element becomes the 3rd, the 5th becomes the 4th, etc.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `perldoc -f splice` From what you have described : `splice @10_el, 2, 1;`

Comment: Usually, `grep` is a better solution.

Comment: @ikegami grep/map are so powerful in perl I couldn't do my job without them +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say we have a 10-element array:

```
my @arr = (0..9);
```

Then we want to remove element 3, or offset 2:

```
my $third_element = splice @arr, 2, 1;
```

`@arr` would now be 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

Answer (score 0):

MAP! It is one of my favorite perl functions..

```
my @out = map { 
$_ #some logic ? $_ : (); #<-- this is your reference variable do stuff here
} @in;
```

Comment: Actually you're misusing map for mere filtering here. Better to use just grep: `my @out = grep { $_ #some logic } @in;`